# Error en Base de datos sqlite

Tags: android

Tengo un mal funcionamiento de sqlite, a la hora de insertar y leer de una tabla de esta BD.
La tabla la tengo definida asi:

```
    String T_DINERO = "CREATE TABLE " + InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO + " (" +
            InContract.DineroColumnas.CUOTA  + "DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
            InContract.DineroColumnas.CENA  + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
            InContract.DineroColumnas.TUNICA  + " DOUBLE NOT NULL" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(T_DINERO);
```

Cuando arranca la app miro si esta vacia esa tabla y si lo esta solo le insertom un registro:

```
      FSDbHelper dbdinero = new FSDbHelper(this );
    SQLiteDatabase databasedinero = dbdinero.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursodinero = databasedinero.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO, null );
    cursodinero.moveToFirst();
    if ( cursodinero.isFirst() == false ) {
        ContentValues contentValuesdinero = new ContentValues();
        double doble;
        doble = 0.00;
        contentValuesdinero.put(InContract.DineroColumnas.CUOTA, doble);
        contentValuesdinero.put(InContract.DineroColumnas.CENA, doble);
        contentValuesdinero.put(InContract.DineroColumnas.TUNICA, doble);
        databasedinero.insert(InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO, null, contentValuesdinero);
    }
    cursodinero.close();
    databasedinero.close();
    dbdinero.close();
```

Pero siempre entra en el if. (como si siempre fuese false y no hubiese insertado nada).

Despues en un activiyty leo esa tabla, pero es como si no existiese ningun registro

```
      FSDbHelper dbdinero = new FSDbHelper(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase databasedinero = dbdinero.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursodinero = databasedinero.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO, null);
    cursodinero.moveToFirst();
    if ( cursodinero.isFirst() == true ) {
        cuota.setText(String.valueOf(cursodinero.getString(InContract.DineroColumnas.CUOTA_INDEX)) + " €");
        cena.setText(String.valueOf(cursodinero.getString(InContract.DineroColumnas.CENA_INDEX)) + " €");
        tunica.setText(String.valueOf(cursodinero.getString(InContract.DineroColumnas.TUNICA_INDEX)) + " €");
    }
    cursodinero.close();
    databasedinero.close();
    dbdinero.close();
```

Como lo puedo solucionar. Gracias. Donde puedo tener el error.

Comment: Empieza por depurar, por ejemplo el `insert` para verificar si la inserción se está ejecutando o no.

Comment: @FernandoDelgadoFernandez, te sugiero revisar el script, revisa la segunda parte de mi respuesta. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para validar si la tabla se encuentra vacía usa el método `getCount()` del cursor, de esta forma inserta el registro.

Es importante en este caso determinar si la inserción fue correcta, esto lo puedes determinar si el resultado de la inserción es diferente a -1 :

```
...
...
Cursor cursodinero = databasedinero.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO, null);
if (cursor.getCount() == 0) 
{               

   ContentValues contentValuesdinero = new ContentValues();
    double doble;
    doble = 0.00;
    contentValuesdinero.put(InContract.DineroColumnas.CUOTA, doble);
    contentValuesdinero.put(InContract.DineroColumnas.CENA, doble);
    contentValuesdinero.put(InContract.DineroColumnas.TUNICA, doble);

    if(databasedinero.insert(InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO, null, contentValuesdinero) != -1){
        Log.i(TAG, "Se pudo insertar el registro.");
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "Error al insertar el registro.");
    }


}
```

Si la inserción no se realiza correctamente es seguramente que la estructura de tu tabla no es correcta, en este caso te sugiero eliminar el caché de la aplicación o la aplicación pero asegurando que la construcción de la estructura de la tabla es correcta.

En tu caso el problema seguramente es debido a que el script para crear la tabla es incorrecto, revisa la linea que es comentada y podrás ver el error:

```
 String T_DINERO = "CREATE TABLE " + InContract.DineroColumnas.TABLA_DINERO + " (" +
      //InContract.DineroColumnas.CUOTA  + "DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
      InContract.DineroColumnas.CUOTA  + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
            InContract.DineroColumnas.CENA  + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, " +
            InContract.DineroColumnas.TUNICA  + " DOUBLE NOT NULL" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(T_DINERO);
```

corrige el script, elimina la aplicación y vuelve a subirla con la corección.